# Showing property of a TCheckBox is false when it should be true

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

I'm using C++ Builder XE, and have a problem with the "Showing" property of a TCheckBox.

I have a `TForm` (ChannelConfigForm), in which there is a `TGroupBox` (AlarmsGroupBox), in which there is a `TCheckBox` (A4_en_Xbox).

Sometimes, I cannot see some of the controls on the form.

According to the help documentation :
"If the Visible properties of a component and all the parents in its parent hierarchy are true, Showing is guaranteed to be true. If one of the parents containing the control has a Visible property value of false, Showing may be either true or false. 
Showing is a read-only property."

To find out what's happening, I wrote the following function to debug the program :
(note : debugf in this function is simply a debug statement I wrote that works similar to printf, which writes debugging stuff to a form)

```
void ShowParentTree(TControl *Control)
{
  wchar_t Name[32];
  static int level=0;
  TWinControl *wc;

  level++;
  if (level==1)
    debugf(L"Parents of control \"%s\" (%s) :",
                       Control->Name.c_str(),
                       Control->ClassName().c_str());

  // Display what Control has as parents and if they're visible and showing
  debugf(L"level %d : %s->Visible  = %s",level,
                       Control->Name.c_str(),
                       Control->Visible?L"true":L"false");
  wc=(TWinControl *)Control;
  debugf(L"level %d : %s->Showing  = %s",level,
                       wc->Name.c_str(),
                       wc->Showing?L"true":L"false");

  if (Control->Parent)
    ShowParentTree((TControl *)Control->Parent);

  level--;
}
```

Sometimes when I show the ChannelConfigForm I get the following :

```
Parents of control "A4_en_Xbox" (TCheckBox) :
level 1 : A4_en_Xbox->Visible  = true
level 1 : A4_en_Xbox->Showing  = false
level 2 : AlarmsGroupBox->Visible  = true
level 2 : AlarmsGroupBox->Showing  = true
level 3 : ChannelConfigForm->Visible  = true
level 3 : ChannelConfigForm->Showing  = true
```

which I understand as meaning that the A4_en_Xbox->Showing property is false when I think it should be true.

Comment: Why am I seeing Delphi tagged here when this isn't Delphi language? The c++builder tag should be enough.

Comment: Because I'm new to this forum (this was my first question) and as far as I remember, C++ builder is written in delphi. Sorry if it's a problem, but I thought that putting tags in for anything relevant should improve the number of answers (or is that not what tags are for?)

Comment: Tags are to categorize things, so that mainly, when helpers are browsing questions to answer, they enter tags for example a combination of [delphi] and [graphics] will list questions all related in some way to Delphi Graphics. If the question doesn't relate to the language, the tag shouldn't be used, even if there is some distant link. We don't even use "rad-studio", if it's related to RAD Studio, we typically use 3 tags, [delphi], [delphi-xe2], and [ide], or whatever version is being used.

Comment: Another example, if I had a question about C# in visual studio, I wouldn't mention Visual Basic just because it's another language the IDE supports.

Comment: @Jerry - then edit the post if you don't agree with the tag.  Plugging Delphi in here gets a lot more viewers than just c++builder and vcl, and the answer a delphi user gives is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what `A4_en_Xbox->HandleAllocated()` returns.  `Showing` will be false if `HandleAllocated()` returns false.  The VCL does not guarantee that a TWinControl-derived component always has an `HWND` allocated at all times.  Sometimes it does free `HWND`s internally and recreates them when needed.

Also, your code has a small logic bug in it.  Not all `TControl` descendants are derived from `TWinControl`, but your code assumes the input `TControl` is always a `TWinControl` descendant.  You need to check for that so you can avoid access the `Showing` property for non-`TWinControl` controls.  You can also do away with the recursion completely, just use a simply loop instead:

```
void ShowParentTree(TControl *Control)
{
    if (!Control)
        return;

    int level = 0;
    TWinControl *wc = dynamic_cast<TWinControl*>(Control);

    debugf(L"Parents of control \"%s\" (%s) :",
                         Control->Name.c_str(),
                         Control->ClassName().c_str());

    // Display what Control has as parents and if they're visible and showing
    do
    {
        level++;

        if (wc)
        {
            debugf(L"level %d : %s Visible = %s, Showing = %s, HandleAllocated = %s",
                level,
                Control->Name.c_str(),
                Control->Visible ? L"true" : L"false",
                wc->Showing ? L"true" : L"false",
                wc->HandleAllocated() ? L"true" : L"false");

        }
        else
        {
            debugf(L"level %d : %s Visible = %s",
                level,
                Control->Name.c_str(),
                Control->Visible ? L"true" : L"false");
        }

        wc = Control->Parent;
        Control = wc;
    }
    while (Control);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, that's helped me quite a lot.